# foreach hopping out without an exception thrown

Tags: c#, generics

This 'foreach' code will quit working and it appears that it's due to some error. However, no exception is thrown. Is there any good reason? The code INSIDE the loop ( ie where the comment is ) never get reached. The failure is while it's enumerating.

```
foreach (DeviceOption<int> d in _deviceOptions.Where(d => d.HasChanges))
{
    //Call some DAL method
}
```

In case this is part of the equation, this is the 'DeviceOption' class code:

```
public class DeviceOption
{
    private object _state;
    public object State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (_state == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            HasChanges = true;
            _state = value;
        }
    }
    public bool UserEditable { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool HasChanges { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayCategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
public class DeviceOption<T> : DeviceOption where T : IComparable
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (value.CompareTo(_value) == 0) { return; }

            HasChanges = true;
            OriginalValue = _value;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public T OriginalValue { get; set; }

}`
```

UPDATE: I figured this out.
I figured this out. Turns out that an invalid cast was happening and the code was faulting. What's odd is that the exception wasn't being thrown. I know this now because I wrapped the code in a try/catch. The behaviour is acting as if this code is running on seperate thread. Is that how LINQ works?

The reason for the cast is because _deviceOptions is a List and contains derived types such as DeviceOption or  or  etc. By adding this to the LINQ, things are fine now: '&& d is DeviceOption'

Here is the updated code and how I fixed the invalid cast:

```
try
        {

            foreach( DeviceOption<int> d in _deviceOptions.Where( d => d.HasChanges && d is DeviceOption<int>) )
            {
                //blah blah blah
            }



        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //this is how I detected the exception. Don't ask why I didn't think of this before :(
            Console.Write( ex.Message );
        }
```

Comment: Well it would do nothing if there simply were no devices with changes..

Comment: Are there any device options where HasChanges is true?

Comment: Are you sure you ever set `State` to something different than the default?

Comment: Are you sure there are objects with `HasChanges == true` inside `_deviceOptions` collection?

Comment: Are you sure you have any values returned in that query?

Comment: Have you confirmed `.Where(d => d.HasChanges)` isn't returning an empty collection, or that `_deviceOptions` is populated by the time the `.Where()` is called?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `HasChanges` and see 1) if it's getting called and 2) if it ever returns `true`

Comment: Have you verified that the call to where actually returns anything but an empty set?

Comment: Can you post some less vague code?  Because you don't even try to catch an exception, so not entirely sure, how you know no exception is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there are no device options where `HasChanges` is True.  In that case the `Where` extension method yields an empty enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given the information you have provided, I have to assume that this query returns an empty enumerable:

```
_deviceOptions.Where(d => d.HasChanges)
```

Have you used the debugger at all to see what exactly is happening?  Pull the query out of the loop expression and see what it contains.